# Command Line <Something> that will find a word and replace the word after it

Tags: regex, windows, command-line, find, replace

I need to modify a generated file with a Visual Studio Pre-Build command line action.

I could build a batch file or a simple console app to do this, but I am wondering if I am reinventing the wheel.

Is there something baked into windows that would allow me to search a file for the first instance of the word **namespace** and replace the word after it with a custom value?

(I am trying to automatically change the namespace on a generated file.)

Answer (score 1):

Windows suffers for baked-in tools like this.  I'd go for [GNU sed](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Since no-one came up with a solution, here is how I would have done it. In AutoHotKey you could use a little script like this:

!0::  ; [Alt]+0 (zero) to execute this, you could assign this to any key you like...

send, {Right}

Send, +^{Right}

Send, NEWSTRING{Space}

Send, {F3}

Return

Basic idea. You open the file in the editor (in this example Notepad). Search for the first word "namespace". Then (after you installed AutoHotKey and added this little script), you press [Alt]+0. On Alt+zero, the script will jump one place to the right(from the highlighted word), them do a [Shift]+[Ctrl]+[Right] to select the next word, then overwrites the highlighted word with your new namespace. After that it sends an [F3] to find the next occurance of the word "namespace". Pressing Alt+Zero again will modify the next word...etc...

If you need this often, then you could make a loop which will be stopped as soon as the "Can not find...." msgbox is presented at the end of the file....